# how extract data from port using php

Tags: php

I want to extract data from the port and want to display it using php.please someone tell me the code in general.I tried the following code somewhere got like it may be from your site only

```
<?php
// Server IP address
$address = "localhost";
// Port to listen
$port =80;

$mysock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_bind($mysock,$address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address'); 
socket_listen($mysock, 5);
$client = socket_accept($mysock);

// read 1024 bytes from client
$input = socket_read($client, 1024);

// write received gprs data to the file
writeToFile('gprs.log', $input);

socket_close($client);
socket_close($mysock);
?> 

<?php
function writeToFile($strFilename, $strText) { 
    if($fp = @fopen($strFilename,"w"))  { 
          $contents = fwrite($fp, $strText); 
          fclose($fp); 
          return true; 
    } else { 
      return false; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

but this is giving error

Comment: Can you add the error details you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is `call to undefined function socket_create`

You'll need to install (or enable) the [Socket PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php): http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php

remove `;` before `extension=sockets.so` or `extension=sockets.dll`

If the error is `socket_bind(): unable to bind address`

You'll need to use higher privileged user to run the script, for example use `sudo script.php`